# Is there a way to save an Image with a View on it in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I have this image with the image of a ruler superimposed on it,[as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccltm.jpg), and I want to save the image with the ruler on it to the camera roll . The ruler is a View component on the Image loaded from the camera roll. I am not able to find a way to do this. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following github repository to superimpose image on video and image.

https://github.com/sagark1510/react-native-video-watermark

Using this git repo i am superimpose image on video succesfully.

This git repo produce some configuration error you need to solve those error.

You can also try this npm and git repository

```
npm i react-native-image-marker
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-marker

https://github.com/JimmyDaddy/react-native-image-marker